# track dropdown for "New Image from plane maker" within Movie clip editor isn't there

Tags: movie-clip-editor

I watched this [Quick tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyr3BUKRl0E) and followed everything perfectly but when I got to 1:06, I noticed that I don't have the drop down but the guy has it.

And to answer your question, Yes I do have the latest version of blender which is version
3.2.2

My Computer

[image: What it looks like]

His Computer

[image: What its meant to look like But it doesn't]

Comment: He is running 3.3.0 alpha in that video and I suspect the drop down is a new 3.3.0 alpha feature.

Comment: Ah right, thanks @MartyFouts :D